# Maven plugin to get Java files from WSDL

Tags: maven, spring-ws, wsdl2java

I am using Maven plugin to convert `wsdl2java`, and it is a copied Maven document from other computer where it successfully generated Java classes from `wsdl`, When I build the same code in my machine, It build's properly, but doesn't generate the Java files. Please let me know where exactly I went wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring WS sample client application</name>
    <description>The Spring WS sample client application</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.12</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <id></id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsimport</goal>
                            </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>cen_1.0.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <keep>true</keep>
                        <packageName>com.untitled.crm.inbound.census.jax</packageName>
                        <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                    </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: is the ``cen_1.0.wsdl`` inside the ``src/main/resources/`` directory?

Comment: yes, It's in the directory, It is working properly in other computer, but I don't understand why it won't work here